# using the ViewPager in Material Design

Tags: android, material-design

Because I used the panorama sliding design in Windows Phone, I developed most of my Android apps using the ViewPager which has a similar design.  The user just slides the pages back and forth to navigate.

Looking at Material Design I'm wondering if the ViewPager has a place.  Should it be replaces by tabs?
thanks,
Dean

Comment: I would use viewpager with pagerslidingtabstips library.  It is very simple and looks good.  There are other versions that meet googles material design guidelines.  If i come across it i woll post the link

Comment: https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip